# Protect ASP.NET WebAPI in .NET 4.7.X with IdentityServer 4 Jwt

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, identityserver3

So, I have set up IdentityServer 4 in a .NET Core 3.1 project. And I have Web application, also .NET Core 3.1 signing in users through OpenId Connect (oidc). Works perfectly.

But I also have another ASP.NET WebAPI project created in **.NET Framework 4.7.2** and I want to let users authenticate to that with a Bearer token created by my IdentityServer 4.

That would work perfectly if that project was also .NET Core. But it's not. It's .NET 4.7.2 and all examples I can find uses .NET Core with "**UseIdentityServerAuthentication**" which is not available in .NET 4.7.2. Or I find examples using "**IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions**", but that requires NuGet for IdentityServer 3 and doesn't seem  to support Jwt tokens created by IdentityServer 4 (or so I understood - might be incorrect).

Can someone push me in the right direction here? The WebAPI project needs to be .NET Framework 4.7.2, that is a technical requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track with `IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions`. you need to use `IdentitySever3.AccessTokenValidation` on API project.
The issue with IdentityServer4 generated tokens is that their type is `at+jwt`, but you need `JWT` on your API, you can easily change the type on IdentityServer like this

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(                
                options =>
                {
                    options.AccessTokenJwtType = "JWT";
                })
```

You may have other issues along the way, which I suggest you to read my blog explaining this with IdentityServer4 and .NET 4.5.2 https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-web-api/

Comment: Cool, I will try that.

I stumbled into "options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;" within "AddIdentityServer". Do you know anything about that in IdentityServer 4, if it's something that should be added or not? It seems to add a second entry under "aud" in my JWT token that holds the address to the identity server /resources.

Comment: Yes you need to add the static resources to make it work with ur API, its added to IDS4 by default proj template. What version of IDS4 do you use? Try my blog its very useful to understand the issues deeper, if you had problem adjusting versions I can help you on sample code